# Why does rebase not allow amending a merge commit?

Tags: git

If the current commit is a merge commit, why does `git rebase -i HEAD~~` doesn't include it among the commits I can amend?

Where does the documentation for `rebase` say that merge commits cannot be amended?

Here's a trivial setup that shows what I mean:

```
git init test_git
cd test_git
touch a
git add a
git commit -m "added a"
git branch feature
git checkout feature
echo "version 1" >a
git commit -a -m "version 1"
git checkout master
echo "version 2" >a
git commit -a -m "version 2"
git merge feature
echo "version 3" >a
git commit -a -m "resolved merge"
git rebase -i HEAD~~
```

At this point, I get the text editor with this message:

```
pick 6746909 version 2
pick 830dbd0 version 1

# Rebase 3848032..d7c0f38 onto 3848032
```

The current (merge) commit is d7c0f38, and it's even mentioned in the comment. But it's not among the commits that I actually get to pick/edit/squash/etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `git rebase`, by default, does not preserve merges. This can be turned off with `--preserve-merges` but the docs state...

> This uses the --interactive machinery internally, but combining it with the --interactive option explicitly is generally not a good idea unless you know what you are doing (see BUGS below).

The reason why is `git rebase` is really replaying your commits on top of another commit, so merges get eliminated. To show why, I've reproduced your repo.

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate
*   5eb2e82 (HEAD -> master) resolved merge
|\  
| * 42cfeab (feature) version 1
* | d6a71b8 version 2
|/  
* 267627b added a
```

And when I run `git rebase -i HEAD~~` I see this:

```
pick d6a71b8 version 2
pick 42cfeab version 1

# Rebase 267627b..5eb2e82 onto 267627b (2 commands)
```

Note that last bit, "onto 267627b" which is the "added a" commit. Those two commits, "version 1" and "version 2" will be patched on top of "added a". The result will be linear, there's no need for a merge.

Because of the branch, there's even a conflict which has to be resolved. Both commits changed the same line from "added a", so no matter what order they're done they'll be in conflict.

Conflict resolved, here's the result.

```
* d6a71b8 (HEAD -> master) version 2
* 267627b added a
```

Where did the "version 1" change go? Resolving the conflict meant "version 1" no longer had any change, so rebase deleted the empty commit. It does this to avoid reintroducing commits that might have already been merged in. You can turn this behavior off with `--keep-empty`, though there's little reason to.

---

If you do want to preserve the merge, what I'd suggest is rebasing your feature branches on top of master first, then merge ***and force a merge***. Let's say you have this.

```
A - B - C - G - H [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature]
```

First, rebase feature onto master.

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master

A - B - C - G - H [master]
                 \
                  D1 - E1 - F1 [feature]
```

This results in a linear history, feature is now on top of master, any conflicts had to be resolved, and feature can be tested with all the updates from master.

Once feature has been tested, it can be merged with master. Since there's no new changes to master, normally a merge would fast forward resulting in this.

```
A - B - C - G - H - D1 - E1 - F1 [feature]
                                 [master]
```

Now it's difficult to see what changes were made as part of feature, important context for future debugging. Instead we want to guarantee the merge commit with `--no-ff`.

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature
```

The result is something like this:

```
A - B - C - G - H ------------ I [master]
                 \            /
                  D1 - E1 - F1 [feature]
```

History is linear, and it's also clear what commits were done together as a branch, and the merge commit can be used to explain the branch.

This is my normal process for merging feature branches.

Comment: Every time I feel I understood basic git, I discover there's another super important thing I didn't know.

Comment: @max The interface makes it seem like Git does 103,487 things, but Git really only does about 4 things. If you learn how the graph (how commits are connected), object IDs, labels (branches and tags), and the staging area work everything else suddenly makes sense.